# stop code execution if any error

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I have code in which I am sourcing multiple codes one after the other. Something like below

```
source("t1.r")
source("t2.r")
source("t3.r")
source("t4.r")
```

While running this main script if any source statement gives an error, I don't want to source any remaining scripts (i.e. don't want to run any subsequent statements).

***I don't want to write if error condition after every source statement. I want to do something universal and at the beginning only.***

What change should I do in the main script to do this?

Comment: Are these files multiple lines of codes? Or are there functions within these files. You can look at `stop` function

Comment: Yes they are multiple lines of codes, but there are no functions inside those.

Comment: stop function, i will have to write after every statement, won't I? That will too inefficient, since there are a lot of source statements in the main script.

Comment: How many files do you have to source in total? I may have a function for you. writing it now

Comment: it will be between 10 and 20. Should not be more than 20. And thanks for putting the effort. :)

Comment: Why would you write the `source` call 20 times for 20 scripts? Iterate on the scripts names/paths and handle exception within the loop, don't copy/paste as per DRY principles.

Comment: If you put those `source` statements in a file (say named `all.R`), then you run `source("all.R")` and it will stop as soon as there is an error. Do you also want to know which script produced the error?

Comment: As suggested by @daroczig , if the `source()` command is written inside a a loop that iterates through the file names, it has to be written only once. And accordingly, it can be wrapped into `tryCatch()`, which would also be written only once.

Answer (score 1):

Edited as per suggested by **Nicola and RHertel**

```
setwd("/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Sub")
scripts<-list.files(pattern="*.R")         

for (f in scripts)
{
  c<-try(source(f))                        
  ifelse (class(c)!="try-error", print(paste("Script Sourced:", f,sep=" ")), setwd("/Users/xxxx/Desktop")             
}
```

This script prints the scripts sourced. That way you can recognise which didnt get sourced.

Comment: Thank you Nicola and RHertel. New code is much improved. Thank you